# to filter ROWs column based on non-existence of key in column of type RECORD(repeated)

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using Bigquery tables to gather vm data, I use a table called **metric**, which has nested repeated columns of **RECORD** type. One of the RECORD type columns called resource.labels contains keyvalue pairs as shown below: (instanceid, project_id etc).

[image]

One of the **key** is **Found**. This **key** may or may not exist depending on the conditions.  So I need a query to select all the records from the **metric** table where the Found key does not exist.

Currently I am unnesting the records like:

`select * from metric, unnest(resource.label) as res where res.key="Found"`

I want a similar query which will give me exactly the records where the **Found** key is not present. I am using standard-sql.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL 
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.metric` t
WHERE 'Found' IN (SELECT key FROM t.resource.labels)
```